# C# ListView Bug

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I keep clicking any ListViews rapidly, the app will eventually freeze and become inaccessible. Any Idea how to prevent this from happening?

to generate the bug:
1. run the app
2. keep clicking the listview randomly as fast as possible
3. the app will then freeze

this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;


namespace DragDropCF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            SetupListView(lv1, new ObservableCollection<String> { "VarOne", "VarTwo", "VarThree" });
            SetupListView(lv2, new ObservableCollection<String> { "VarFour", "VarFive", "VarSix", "VarSeven" });
            SetupListView(lv3, new ObservableCollection<String> { "VarEight", "VarNine", "VarTen", "VarEleven", "VarTwelve" });
        }

        private void SetupListView(ListView listView, ObservableCollection<String> itemsSource)
        {
            listView.ItemsSource = itemsSource;
            listView.AllowDrop = true;
            listView.CanDrag = true;
            listView.CanDragItems = true;
            listView.CanReorderItems = true;


            listView.DragItemsStarting += ListView_DragItemsStarting;
            lv1.DragEnter += Lv1_DragEnter;
            lv1.Drop += Lv1_Drop;
        }

        private void Lv1_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Lv1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ListView_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also I see that you are using an ObservableCollection. Is this wpf?

Comment: In `SetupListView` you have `lv1.DragEnter += Lv1_DragEnter;` and the line below it. Is that supposed to be there? It seems odd since you are sending in 3 different list views in your constructor. I'd guess that is supposed to be `listView.DragEnter += Lv1_DragEnter;` instead, which could also be suspect depending on what you're doing.